# SQL insert into, Sequecence.Nextval not working

Tags: sql, insert, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying the following query but get an error as mentioned below,
i have to insert names that exist in the `data excel` table not present in the
`person` table but in `data_excel_1928` table there exist multiple enteries of `name`,`id` is primary key in persons table.

```
 INSERT INTO Person (Name,source,id)
SELECT Distinct(A.Person_Name),source,seq.nextval
      FROM Data_Excel_1928 A
LEFT OUTER JOIN Person B
        ON A.Person_name = B.Name
     WHERE B.Name IS NULL
```

> *Cause:    The specified sequence number (CURRVAL or NEXTVAL) is inappropriate
>             here in the statement.
>
> *Action:   Remove the sequence number.

Comment: In the data_excel names have multiple enteries so i want to select Distinct/Unique names;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this,

```
INSERT INTO Person (NAME,SOURCE,ID)
SELECT person_name, SOURCE, seq.nextval
FROM  
(
     SELECT Distinct A.Person_Name person_name,source
           FROM Data_Excel_1928 A
     LEFT OUTER JOIN Person B
             ON A.Person_name = B.Name
          WHERE B.NAME IS NULL
);
```